# Can I use a parameter in Array of strings exported as const

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array:

```
const PossibleFruits = [
  "apples",
  "bananas",
  "pears"
] as const

export getFruits = (fruits: PossibleFruits) => {
  console.log(fruits);
}
```

Then:

```
const apple = getFruits("apples"); // logs "apples"
const pear = getFruits("pears"); // logs "pears"
const plum = getFruits("plums"); // compilation error !
```

But I would like to be able to have the possibility to have a parameter there, so I would be allowed to use:

```
cosnt twoApples = getFruits("two apples"); // should log "two apples"
const eightPears = getFruits("eight pears"); // should log "eight pears"
const threePlums = getFruits("three plums"); // I expect compilation errors.
```

Is this possible using typescript features ?

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: to add type restriction to a parameter in the constructor of a class that would use this type

Comment: It would make ***far*** more sense to accept two parameters in the function - the name of the fruit (ideally as a concrete type, not an string) and an integer to count how many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (fruits: PossibleFruits)

First, this type doesn't work, since PossibleFruits isn't a type. I think you meant to do `(fruits: typeof PossibleFruits[number])`, which turns the array into a union of all the elements in the array. Ie, `'apples' | 'pears' | 'plums'`.

Moving on to your question, this can be done with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html). If you want to allow any prefix (including an empty string), followed by one of the fruits, that would look like:

```
export const getFruits = (fruits: `${string}${typeof PossibleFruits[number]}`) => {
  console.log(fruits);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACiCECWAjANgUwGICcCuyUEMAvDANoBQMMARAIYAOTWEdANDfag2Hw3ZdadJpga52VALoxBMUJChUqmAB5MQuWIugwA5pih5CxMjAAUAMwJEIALhgADACQBvaLmRh9AX3dQAJ5iIFbwiCgYOLbEFGD4ALaomLjSvk4AlGQAfDBu3LogWAB06CD61jEQGQDcVL4qurDMrJjmhsZVFowsbHS1MAD0gzBl%20iQ9rVJNMGIS7UYmdt1zkv01QyNjE6vT4HqsiQudphAr6InsA8MKIAlMyOgMUMjgMCm4WjAAhI37sFAAO4gACCvUwJHIHSWxG6QJAcnBVw2NwgAAsQPh0AATUblejwxFTOhUGaYZD6NFQODiSTHGFnOjkymwXbrTYwdGYnF4-T0ZlU2a0vZKGBQNG4TCYOAXBKQgyLLp0cWStqHOXsm4ASXeGkwwB0dweTxebw%20WggxSAA)

If you want to allow suffixes too, you can do:

```
export const getFruits = (fruits: `${string}${typeof PossibleFruits[number]}${string}`) => {
  console.log(fruits);
}
```